# Getting Warning include(): Failed opening 'Mage/0/Helper/Core.php' for inclusion

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, wordpress

I am using **Fishpig** to integrate my **blog into my magento** installation. It is all working but when I try switching themes I get the following warning and then my theme switches back to the default.

> include(): Failed opening 'Mage/0/Helper/Core.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/var/www/site/app/code/local:/var/www/site/app/code/community:/var/www/site/app/code/core:/var/www/site/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in /var/www/site/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Im having a hard time tracking this error down because I can not figure out what the 0 represents in

`Mage/0/Helper/Core.php`